# Term for the Pseudo Code Inside of an Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs

Let's say you have something like the following:

```
ng-options="item.Name for item in filters"
```

Is the code related to `ng-options` considered JavaScript?  Or is there a term Angular uses to call this code that you embed inside of HTML directives?

Answer (score 2):

That code can be a lot of things. A string, an array, a function. Most of the time, Angular calls this an angular expression. Check out http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

from the docs:

> - **Context**: JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global window. In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.
> - **Forgiving**: In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties generates ReferenceError or TypeError. In Angular, expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null.
> - **No Control Flow Statements**: you cannot use the following in an Angular expression: conditionals, loops, or exceptions.
> - **Filters**: You can use filters within expressions to format data before displaying it.